# magento extension that save product for later use same as jabong

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

i have one query for magento extension. i want free or paid magento extension that save product for later us. if you want to see the demo . just open the [jabong](http://www.jabong.com/) and try to add one product as save for later. and you will get that product in to save list. i am searching for similar kind of magento extension. but i am not able to find it. so, if any one have any good reference. please share with me

Thanks to all my friends.

Answer (score 3):

I think your required feature is default in Magento.

Magento provides wishlist feature by default, but it requires user to be logged in at time of adding product to wishlist.

Hope this will help.

Comment: thnx for reply but in jabong you dont need to log in and you can add and it will be saved for next time

Comment: i think jabong saving products in cookies or guest session. because there is a message saying **`"Please login to help us remember your items"`**

Comment: yes..I think so but I tried to search an extension for it. would you be able to provide any reference for it??

Answer (score 0):

If you want a paid extension, then this will help you.. http://www.magentogarden.com/magento-guest-wishlist.html. This is a paid extension that helps you to add products to wishlist without login and this has some good reviews also.. Hope this helps. Cheers :)

Comment: I ll look into this. thnx to share